# DataGrid columns width

Tags: c#, winforms, datagrid

How can I set the width of a column on a `DataGrid` in `WinForms`?

In a `DataGridView` I usally use `AutoSizeMode` on the columns but there's seem to be no way to do this with `DataGrid`.

They only property I found is `PreferredColumnWidth` but this changes the width of all columns.

Comment: WinForms sorry, added to the OP.

Comment: _The DataGridView control replaces and adds functionality to the DataGrid control_ - so why you want to use `DataGrid` instead of `DataGridView`?

Comment: I'm building a grid with a treeview functionality, DataGrid makes it real simple to do.

Answer (score -1):

Perhaps you could set column width in code, for example your column is named "Column1" you could try:

```
Column1.Width = 500;
```

in your form class.